# MVC3 Regular Expression Validator - "Syntax Error In Regular Expression"

Tags: jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, validation

I am trying to add a "RegularExpression" attribute to a property in a ViewModel

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W+)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?i-msnx:(?!.*pass|.*password|.*word|.*god|.*\s))(?!^.*\n)^((.))+$.*$", ErrorMessage = "Password does not meet requirements.")]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

When the validation occurs, I get the following exception from Visual Studio:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error in regular expression
```

This is the same exact regular expression that I am defining in the web.config when defining the Membership provider:

```
passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W+)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?i-msnx:(?!.*pass|.*password|.*word|.*god|.*\s))(?!^.*\n)^((.))+$.*$"
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error when using the regular expression in the Model attribute?

Comment: What's wrong with `god`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JScript is Microsoft's version of ECMAScript, which supports an extremely limited set of regex features compared to .NET.  Your biggest problem is that it doesn't support inline modifiers like `(?i:xyz)`.  There also seems to be no way to pass modifiers separately, like you could if you were using C# or JScript directly.  If you want to exclude things case-insensitively, you're kinda screwed.

Be aware, too, that character-class shorthands like `\d` and `\W` have different meanings on the server (.NET) than they do on the client (JScript).  If you want the regex to work the same on both sides, you might want to be more specific.  Here's an example, broken down for clarity:

```
^
(?=\S{8,}$)           # eight or more non-whitespace characters
(?=.*[0-9])           # at least one digit
(?=.*[a-z])           # at least one lowercase letter
(?=.*[A-Z])           # at least one uppercase letter
(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])    # at least one non-letter, non-digit
(?!.*(?:pass|word|god|PASS|WORD|GOD))
.+$
```

As you can see, I'm only excluding all-lowercase or all-uppercase versions of `pass`, `word`, etc., which isn't really satisfactory.  If you really need to exclude or require whole words case-insensitively, you may have to use a different kind of validator.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem you are seeing is a portion of the regular expression is unsupported in Javascript. I am suspicious of `i-msnx:` but I am by no means a regular expression expert. I recommend you cut you regular expression in half until the error goes away so you can narrow it down.